# Why does my code show error while knitting but not when i run the chunk separately?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr

When running all the chunks in the markdown file it works perfectly but when I knit it shows an error for the select function.
I have called `library(dplyr)` so I don't see why there should be an error.

If I remove the select function and use $len in the later code there is no problem. I don't understand why the select function is giving an error. 
Also, the Toothgrowth data has not been modified before this thus there are 60 observations of 3 variables len,supp and dose.

```
D.5<-ToothGrowth%>%filter(dose==0.5)%>%select(len)

D1<-ToothGrowth%>%filter(dose==1)%>%select(len)  

D2<-ToothGrowth%>%filter(dose==2)%>%select(len)
```

> error in select(.,len) unused argument (len)

this is the error message

Comment: I guess you used `library(dplyr)` in a separate chunk. Did you run that before running the chunk containing this code?

Comment: Try running `detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)` and then run your code.

Comment: You have a name collision between `MASS::select` and `dplyr::select`, either `detach` `MASS` or call dplyr select explicitly `ToothGrowth%>%filter(dose==0.5)%>%dplyr::select(len)`